# MySQL error "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a table from an sql dump with a size of 4.7G which includes longblobs using the following command:

```
mysql --max-allowed-packet=2048M -uroot -p otobo < /backup/article_data_mime_plain.sql
```

even though the option "--max-allowed-packet" it's usually more then enough when set to "512M" in this particular case not even 2G which is the allowed limit seems to be usefull at all giving the following output:

> ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 2270: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Thanks in advance, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You need to split your data or increase the limit on the server. You can't increase the limit from the client.

Comment: May you describe of which variable are talking about?
I'm yes working on the server.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet`. But `mysql` is not the server, it's a client. The server binary is probably called `mysqld` and it's a system service.

Comment: @continius  Double check your version of MySQL for upper limit of  max_allowed_packet, please.  Never seen it be more than 1G for the upper limit.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to increase the value of the net_buffer_length configuration variable on the client, as it can affect the size of the packets being transmitted during the dump process. The default value is 16384 bytes. For example:

```
[mysql]
net_buffer_length=128K
```

Once you have made the changes, you can retry the database dump and it should complete successfully.

Comment: Tried to set the variable as you described  and restarted the server but it still gives the same error

Comment: Check the current value of max_allowed_packet: You can check the current value of max_allowed_packet by executing the following query in the MySQL client: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';. Ensure that the value you've set in the configuration file is reflected in the output of this query.